# keeps showing "^@" repeatedly

Tags: pi-3

I boot just fine but when it is ready for login it repeatedly shows "^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@..." forever. Please help me fix this. Thanks!

Comment: where does it show that?

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) But your question is very vague. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Comment: Does it do the same if you unplug your USB keyboard?